# Zend Framework: Remove LDAP attribute

Tags: zend-framework, attributes, ldap

I need to remove an LDAP attribute from a node (from ZFW).

What I usually do in LDAP (directly from console) to do this is as bellow:

```
CODE: SELECT ALL
ldapmodify [... irrelevant data removed...]
dn: uid=someuser,ou=users,dc=company,dc=com
changetype: modify
delete: pwdAccountLockedTime
```

In PHP removing attributes is possible by using ldap_mod_del (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-mod-del.php).

**Is there any built-in function in Zend Framework to do the same operation?**

Answer (score 0):

The password policy overlay delete that attributes when the lock time expires. To do it yourself you would at least require the appropriate permissions in slapd.conf. It's an admin action, not a general user action.

Comment: Thank you EJP. I know that, what I'm after is to remove some attribute. pwdAccountLockedTime is just an example.
(In fact I have solved the pwdAccountLockedTime issue by setting an expiration time in the past! This way, when user logins, the locked time duration is exceeded and the one can successfully login.)